# Java: File relative path - No File Found

Tags: java, spring

I coding a java send mail program which attach a test report file at relative path.

Questions: 
How to setup the path so that the file can be found?

Test Report Directory:

> com.securister\report\Test-Report.html

Java File:

> com.securister\src\test\java\com\securister\TestManager

I tried setup like

> String filename = "\..\..\..\..\..\..\report\Test-Report.html"

but end up no file found.

Should i using classpath?

Comment: Do you mean to use `"../../../"` pattern ? A single dot just means the current dir.

Comment: why you don't add it to the resources folder?

Comment: Which resource folder do i uses? How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the structure of `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`, put the

target file under the resource in a test as I guess

, And read the file from the path `src/test/resources/report/Test-Report.html`

Answer (score 0):

You can print the current directory of your java program where it is executed from with this java code,

```java
System.out.println("CurrentDir: " + (new File(".").getCanonicalPath()));
```

Say it prints,

`CurrentDir: D:\XXX\workspace\test`
Then you can correctly choose a path through which your file can be correctly located.

Most likely, your src folder should be in the test directory and in that case you can either move your file from src folder to test folder or refer your file in your code like this,

..\Test-Report.html

which should be able to read your file.

Let me know if this works.